An unhandled exception of type 'System.ArgumentException' occurred in BouncyCastle.Crypto.dll Scalar is not in the interval [1, n - 1]
static void Main(string[] args)
{
     new Thread(() =>
     {
         GetEthPrice();
     }).Start();

     try
     {
         var web3 = new Web3("https://mainnet.infura.io/v3/90068c63d5204a47a8ec864f10ad5fb2");
         using (StreamReader file = new StreamReader("keys.txt"))
         {
             string line;
             while ((line = file.ReadLine()) != null)
             {
                 if (treADINT > 10)
                 {
                     Thread.Sleep(500);
                 }
                 else
                 {
                     new Thread(() =>
                     {
                         Run(EthECKey.GetPublicAddress(line), line);
                     }).Start();
                 }
             }
         }
     }
     catch { }
     Console.ReadKey();

}

After debug, code is running until 'Run(EthECKey.GetPublicAddress(line), line);' and getting the error in title. What can I change to stop the error?

Exceptions come with a much more extensive stacktrace. Add it to the question, properly formatted.
